# international characters in url, mvc filtering issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I have a problem with filtering in asp.net mvc.
I have a page with listed collection and the filter.
Filter has values for filtering collection, it is: category, status and the containing string. The problem is in internationalisation-application can be on more than one language, so the containing string can be special character, for example: ü

My route is `List/{category}/{status}/{containingString}`

should I use get method for sending also the containingString or should I use post method.
I am using little trick now, my form is posting to another action method of same controller, this controller get category and status from url and containingString from Request.Form and then redirect to List action method, containingString I am putting in TempData...as you see it is a some kind of dirty hack and I don't like it myself...

Anyone for a better solution to this problem?

Thanks

p.s. stackoverflow rocks!

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the diacritics in the Router?